# How do I convert negative numbers that are strings into integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataTable like:

| Game Script |
| --- |
| -1.95 |
| +1.3 |
| -1.2 |
| +1.54 |

How should I convert negative numbers that are strings into integers?

This is would I have tried so far

```
full_data['Game Script'] = full_data['Game Script'].apply(lambda X: X.replace('+',''))
full_data['Game Script'] = full_data['Game Script'].apply(lambda X: int(X))
```

I get the following exception:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1.85'
```

Comment: [‌](http://google.com)`astype`

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1.85'` What do you want the result to be when you do this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
full_data['Game Script'] = full_data['Game Script'].astype('int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use the `eval()` function here:

```py
full_data['Game Script'] = eval(full_data['Game Script'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `pd.to_numeric`

```
full_data['Game Script'] = pd.to_numeric(full_data['Game Script'])
Out[21]: 
0   -1.95
1    1.30
2   -1.20
3    1.54
Name: GameScript, dtype: float64
```